# Javascript put attribute to a element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using uikit and to open a dropdown i can set some attributes like:

```
data-uk-dropdown="{mode:'click',justify:'#my-id',}"
```

this kind of way it's usable from html view in the input. Is it possible use the `justify` directly from javascript? I mean something like:

```
 $(document).on('focusin', '#my-id', function () {
        $('.uk-dropdown').justifly('#my-id');
    });
```

of course `$('.uk-dropdown').justifly('#my-id');` it's not the correct way and it's not working.

Comment: which is the plugin used.. do you have a link to that plugin

Comment: I'm using Uikit @ArunPJohny

Answer (score 3):

You need to use `.attr()` for setting the attribute value:

```
 $('.uk-dropdown').attr('justifly','#my-id');
```

for setting multiple attributes:

```
  $('.uk-dropdown').attr({'mode':'click','justify':'#my-id'});
```

Comment: mmh seems the correct solution but try to see here: http://jsfiddle.net/8y48q/51/ not works :(

Comment: Try in this way: http://jsfiddle.net/8y48q/52/ i still can't justify the dropdown when i click on the input text. If you click on the right button it is justified

Comment: have you tried to click in the input text? See the difference between the click on the button and from the input. If you click in the input text for first you will see that the drodown is smaller that the input. Then, click in the button on the right of the input text. You will see the dropdown at the same width of the input text. I need do this via javascript